# How do I reset my MAAS username/password?

Tags: maas

I've set up [MAAS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/MAAS) but forgot the username and password, how can I reset it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sudo maas changepassword <user>`, where user is the user you want the password changed:

```
cerdea@capiau:/var/log/maas$ sudo maas changepassword maas-root
Changing password for user 'maas-root' 
Password: 
Password (again): 
Password changed successfully for user 'maas-root'
cerdea@capiau:/var/log/maas$
```

Of course, you may need to **find** which user to change the password for:

```
matsubara@tancho [~]$ sudo maas shell

In [1]: from maasserver.models import User

In [2]: User.objects.all()
Out[2]: [<User: maas-init-node>, <User: admin>]

In [3]:
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 the correct command to get shell is "sudo maas-region shell"

Answer (score 1):

in case you're using Ubuntu 14.04Lts with Icehouse the command to use is

`maas-region-admin changepassword <user>` where user is the user you want the password changed:

```
$: sudo maas-region-admin changepassword user
Changing password for user 'user'
Password: 
Password (again): 
Password changed successfully for user 'user'
```

Comment: "maas-region-admin" is deprecated in 16.04 and "maas-region" should be used